# My splash screen is loading too slow

Tags: android

I am beginner in android development, I am facing issue that " My android app splash screen is loading too slow " please help me in fixing this issue.

Here is my spash.java source code :

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class Splash extends Activity {

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

            ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
            actionBar.hide();

            Thread t =new Thread(){
                public void run(){
                    try{
                        sleep(10000);
                    }catch(InterruptedException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }finally{
                        Intent i =new Intent(Splash.this,MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                }
            };
            t.start();
        }
        @Override
        public void onPause(){
            super.onPause();
            finish();
        }

    }
```

Comment: change sleep time , put 2000 it wll be for 2 seconds @Rohith

Comment: `sleep(10000);` It means , your Splash screen needs 10 second to go to the next Activity . Set something like 1000 or 2000 to faster loding .

Comment: @JhamanDas i should replace sleep(10000); with sleep(2000); Right ?

Comment: Change Sleep Time  to Either `2000` or `1000`.

Comment: yes change to 1000 or 2000 @Rohith

Comment: @JhamanDas  Thanx for the Help :-)

Comment: Appreciate me by putting accept on my answer @Rohith

Comment: @ZahidulIslam Thanx for the help :-)

Comment: Your sleep time is long. Just decrease it for 3000 or 2000 which will be 3 or 2 seconds. You can use _Handler_ too

Comment: thanx all for help :-)

Comment: Also, don't have to call `getActionBar().hide()` to hide your actionbar, because as you are inheriting android `Activity`, the action bar won't display. If you were inheriting `AppCompatActivity`, the action bar would display, and you would have to hide it manually as you did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change `sleep time` , put `2000` instead of `10000` it will be for 2 seconds

Comment: Thanx for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try below code it will work.

```
public class ViewSplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener,Runnable {
    RelativeLayout rltvGetstarted;
    Activity thisActivity;
    private Handler mHandler;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        /*if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Window window = getWindow();
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }*/
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.act_splashscreen);
        mHandler = new Handler();
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        /*init*/
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        thisActivity = this;
        rltvGetstarted = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rltv_getstarted);
        rltvGetstarted.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v==rltvGetstarted){
            CM.startActivity(thisActivity,ViewMobileNo.class);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //if user already login
        //CM.startActivity(thisActivity,ViewMobileNo.class);
        CM.startActivity(thisActivity,ViewBase.class);
        finish();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanx for the answer

Answer (score 0):

**In your code you have to change `Thread` sleep time take load more..**

see below code with updated, here  `sleep(10000);` to change  `sleep(2000);`

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class Splash extends Activity {

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.hide();

        Thread t =new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    sleep(2000);
                }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally{
                    Intent i =new Intent(Splash.this,MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
    }
    @Override
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanx for the answer

Comment: but i wanna explain with code then give answer.@jaydroider